# How to install Flash on opera browser on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: flash, 16.10, opera

I'm trying to install Flash for Opera latest version on Ubuntu 16.10 but everything I have found and tried failed. It works fine however on Firefox and Chrome. Has anybody been able to successfully make it work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

- Enable the [Canonical Partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner).
- Install the `adobe-flashplugin` package.
- Create a symlink using this command:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so /usr/lib/opera/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so
  ```
- Restart Opera.

*Edit:*

The symlink is possibly not needed with the latest Opera version.